# Database column data having linebreaks are ignored when retrieved from Hibernate?

Tags: spring, html, spring-4

A CLOB database column data has linebreaks :

[image]

When I retrieve it and display the data inside a html table cell then the linebreaks are ignored :

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String getPrevisionRessourceAutreForProduit(Objectif produit) {

        String hql = "select to_char(r.ress_comment_1) " + 
                     "from ressource r join type_ressource t on r.type_ress_code = t.type_ress_code " + 
                     "left join objectif o on r.obj_code = o.obj_code " + 
                     "where o.obj_code = " + produit.getCode().toString() + " and upper(t.type_ress_code) = 'AUT'";

        Session sessionDynamic = Utils.createDynamicSession(env);

        Query query = sessionDynamic.createSQLQuery(hql);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> list = (List<String>) query.list();

        sessionDynamic.close();

        if (list.isEmpty())
            return "";
        else
            return list.get(0) == null ? "" : list.get(0);

    }
```

[image]

So how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by enclosing the data inside the tags `<pre>...</pre>`